# What happened to this bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty

There was a 100 rep bounty on this question: [How can I graphically represent width, height and depth dimensions?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2378/how-can-i-graphically-represent-width-height-and-depth-dimensions)

The bounty period ended a little while ago and since the asker commented his approval of my answer I figured I would get the bounty. However, well, no answers have been accepted. Is there some sort of mechanism to ensure that people actually award the bounties they set?

Comment: It's a shame that this happened you know, the more reputation this site gives out, the more loyal the users and therefore the more likely that the statistics will increase eh?

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the bounty, one of 2 things needed to happen.

1. The bounty starter clicks the reward bounty button, e.g. +100, within the bounty period.

   - The answerer is rewarded the whole bounty amount.
2. The bounty starter does not click the reward bounty button.

   - The answer that:

     - … has ≥ 2 upvotes **and**
     - … is the highest voted answer when the bounty period ends **and**
     - … is submitted after the bounty
   - … is rewarded with half the bounty amount.

I see that neither answer has received any votes, nor did the original poster post anything. Thus, it seems likely that the reputation disappeared. Sorry to see it go, but sometimes it happens...

Answer (score 0):

The detailed bounty rules are at

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty

Note that there has been one minor tweak we didn't document there quite yet; if the question owner accepts an answer, but does not otherwise award the bounty, we assume they wanted to and will grant the bounty to the accepted answer at the end of the bounty period.